# Why does Powershell think I'm trying to return an object[] rather then a DataTable?

Tags: powershell

I have the following PS function:

```
function GetBuildData {
    [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection] $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand] $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter] $adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    [System.Data.DataTable] $dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    
    try {
        [string] $connStr = "myConnectionString"
        
        $conn.ConnectionString = $connStr
        $cmd.Connection = $conn
        $cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TestTable"
        
        $conn.Open
        
        $adapter.SelectCommand = $cmd
    
        $adapter.Fill($dt)
        
        $conn.Close
    }
    catch [system.exception]
    {
        Write-Host $_
    }
    finally {
        $adapter.Dispose
        $cmd.Dispose
        $conn.Dispose
    }
    
    return $dt
}
```

Most of the function has been removed for brevity. The problem I have is when I call the function like so:

`[System.Data.DataTable] $buildData = GetBuildData`

I get the following error:

> Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]"
> to type "System.Data.DataTable".

I've already double-checked, and `$dt` does contain data. For example, the number of Rows.Count is 1 which is expected. Why does Powershell think that I'm wanting an object[] array returned when it's obvious that the $dt variable is a DataTable?

Comment: what line is the error occurring on? the error message should provide the line and character number. I am assuming it happens here: $adapter.Fill($dt) ??

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't know about the other issues people are bringing up, but I can think of two possible reasons why you're getting back an `Object[]`.

1. It might be that you have uncaptured output somewhere else in the function. In your case, `Fill` returns an `int`. Try adding this to the end of your function calls:

   ```
   | Out-Null
   ```

   E.g.,

   ```
   $adapter.Fill($dt) | Out-Null
   ```

   If any statement returns a value and you're not capturing it, the output will be included in your return value, and since you'll have multiple return values at that point, PowerShell will stuff them all into an array.
2. The other possibility is that PowerShell converts returned collections of all sorts into `Object[]`s. Use the `,` operator to return the unmangled value:

   ```
   return , $dt
   ```

   The `,` creates an array containing only the value that follows. As near as I can guess, this causes PowerShell to automatically unroll the outermost array and leave the value alone, since the actual return value is now an array that only contains a single value.

   The `return` is actually optional, since uncaptured values are included in the return value.

   Just ran into this one myself yesterday. I can't for the life of me figure out why anyone would think silently converting to `Object[]` is useful.

Comment: That's the answer! Now I can go repair the wall from the damage caused by my head. Ditto on "I can't for the life of me figure out why anyone would think silently converting to `Object[]` is useful." Maybe Microsoft has a kickback deal with a wall repair contractor?

Comment: BTW, I see that this can be combined with **return**, i.e. `return , $dt` also works if you want to return **$dt** unconverted and end the function right there.

Comment: One more note I'd like to add is that the conversion takes place even if you don't use the **return** keyword. If the last expression evaluated is **$dt** alone, the function returns an object array.

Comment: @AdiInbar You're right about `return , $dt` syntax. I found out later that what the `,` operator does, when used like this, is put the argument into the array. I think what's happening is that PowerShell sees that we have an array of one element and automatically unwraps it. This works because having PowerShell unwrap the value bypasses the automatic conversion from collection to `Object[]`. Given that, the return mechanism just works in the usual way: any uncaptured value is returned. That's why it works with or without `return`.

Comment: @AdiInbar can you give me the name of the contractor you used to fix your wall? I need to fix mine as well.

Answer (score 0):

You do have a couple of issues in what you posted. Since you explicitly create a DataTable object with `New-Object System.Data.DataTable`, there is no reason to also coerce it to the DataTable type with `[System.Data.DataTable]`. The same is true for when you call the function. You are returning a DataTable object, so that is what you will get back. Also if you did want to specify the variable type, there should not be a space between the type identifier and the variable name. Regardless, these issues would not cause the behavior that you are seeing. I ran this code:

```
function GetBuildData {
    $dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    $column1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'Col1'
    $column2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn 'Col2'
    $dt.columns.add($column1)
    $dt.columns.add($column2)
    $row = $dt.NewRow()
    $row.col1 = '1'
    $row.col2 = '2'
    $dt.rows.add($row)

    return $dt
}

$buildData = GetBuildData
$buildData
Col1                                                                     Col2
----                                                                     ----
1                                                                        2
```

And it worked just fine. I suspect that the bit that is causing your problem is probably in the bit that you excluded for brevity. Shortcuts rarely are and you rarely get accurate answers from partial data.

Comment: I've added the whole of the function, just in case that gives any clues as to why it's not working for me.

Comment: In the function, if you have it output the contents of $dt, does it have data in it? If you do $dt.GetType() in the function, what does it think $dt is?

Comment: I would also suggest getting rid of all those type identifiers when you create variables. They are unnecessary and may be causing the issue although I don't think so.

Comment: @EBGreen If a value of a different type will really cause a failure (as well could be the case if the OP is expecting a `DataTable` and is getting an `Object[]`), there's nothing wrong with the type declaration. It serves as a fail early/fast check, which probably made this problem more clear, actually.

Answer (score 0):

A contributing factor is that you're not actually calling the open and close methods, but referring to them instead.  PowerShell is outputting a reference to these methods as well as the datatable (which I imagine isn't actually populated due to the fact that the connection isn't open).

You need to include the parentheses on the open/close methods like this:

```
$conn.Open()
...
$conn.Close()
```

You also need to beware of methods which return values (.Add() methods are notorious for this) that you're not consuming either by assigning to a variable or piping to out-null.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to void out all your dot commands that aren't assigned to variables

```
function GetBuildData {
    [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection] $conn = New-Object   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand] $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter] $adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    [System.Data.DataTable] $dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

    try {
        [string] $connStr = "myConnectionString"

        $conn.ConnectionString = $connStr
        $cmd.Connection = $conn
        $cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TestTable"

        [void]$conn.Open

        $adapter.SelectCommand = $cmd

        $adapter.Fill($dt)

        [void]$conn.Close
    }
    catch [system.exception]
    {
        Write-Host $_
    }
    finally {
         [void]$adapter.Dispose
         [void]$cmd.Dispose
         [void]$conn.Dispose
    }

    $dt
}
```

As for your question *Why?* ... Read Keith Hill's Blog: [how does return work powershell functions](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/107328-how-does-return-work-powershell-functions.html)