# Why does my PowerShell function return Object[] instead of string[]?

Tags: powershell

I wrote the following function to split a string into an array of strings. There are circumstances when the input is $null, in which case the function should return $null, or when the input already is a string array, in which case the input should be returned as-is.

```
function Split-Tests($tests)
{
    if ($tests -eq $null)
    {
        return $tests
    }
    if (($tests.GetType() -eq [string[]]) -and $tests.Count -ne 1)
    {
        return $tests
    }
    return ([string]$tests).Split(",")
}
```

The function should return either $null, or a string array. However, when I call this function like `Split-Tests "1,2,3"`, the returned value has type object[] even though the string.Split function returns string[].

I tried an explicit cast to string[] (`return [string[]](([string]$tests).Split(","))`) instead, and I tried the `[OutputType([string[]])]` attribute, but the return type remained at object[].

As a final resort, I cast the result of the function invocation to [string[]]. That works, but I would rather define the return type *within* the function that outside it. Can you help me?

Edit: I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974676/why-does-powershell-think-im-trying-to-return-an-object-rather-then-a-datatab?rq=1) indicating that I could add a comma between "return" and the return value. Unfortunately, in my case it didn't help. Not even "Write-Output" mentioned [in this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61439620/how-can-i-return-a-byte-array-rather-than-an-object-array-from-a-powershell-fu?rq=1) made a change.

Edit again: The comma trick did it, I must've done something wrong in my first attempt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour. Unlike other programming languages, PowerShell *unrolls* arrays and outputs them element-by-element to the *pipeline*, as a *stream*. Even the `return` statement in PowerShell doesn't actually *return* the given object as-is, but outputs to the pipeline as well.

I. e.

> ```sh
> return ([string]$tests).Split(",")
> ```

is just a shortcut for:

```sh
([string]$tests).Split(",")   # Output to the pipeline
return                        # Return from the function
```

When the output gets captured into a variable, PowerShell just sees the **individual elements** as passed to the pipeline. It doesn't know about the original array type. As the values from the pipeline could be of **different types**, it can only create a generic `object[]` array, which accepts any element type.

```sh
Function Fun { return 1,2,3,'a','b','c' }
$x = Fun  # Now x contains 3 ints and 3 strings.
```

To force output of a `string[]` array, you can use the unary form of the [comma-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#comma-operator-) in front of the array to **prevent enumeration**:

```sh
function Split-Tests( $tests)
{
    if ($tests -eq $null)
    {
        return $tests
    }
    if (($tests.GetType() -eq [string[]]) -and $tests.Count -ne 1)
    {
        return ,$tests
    }
    ,([string]$tests).Split(",")  # No return statement needed here
}

$a = Split-Tests "1,2,3"
$a.GetType().Name   # Outputs "String[]"
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I tried it again, carefully, and it worked :-)

Comment: I tried the same with a function returning a byte array but it does not work, it always returns an array of objects :-( @zett42 Any idea why ?

Comment: @fededim Hard to say without seeing code.

Comment: @zett42 yep you are right, the problem was that I was missing the outputtype attribute, adding that the comma operator works fine. You can check the code [here function decryptBytes](https://github.com/fededim/BinaryToPowershellScript/blob/master/BinaryToPowershellScript/Program.cs#L89).